# How can I parse pandas datetime values which are in an inconsitent date format into a uniform date format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have datetime values in a dataframe which have different formats i.e some are in the form `yyyy-mm-dd` and some are in the form `yyyy-dd-mm`. I want to convert all of them into one format `yyyy-mm-dd`. The problem only exists for months and dates upto 12 i.e `2021-03-09` is recorded as `2021-09-03` or `2021-04-06` is recorded as `2021-06-04`, `2019-11-12` is recorded as `2019-12-11` etc. Now my data has one unique quality all of it is recorded on a Tuesday so the day must always be a Tuesday so the wrongly represented data will have dates which don't fall on a Tuesday. I tried creating a parsing function like this

```
import datetime
def parse_date(date):
  if date.weekday() != 1:  
    year,day,month = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").split('-')
 else:
    year, month,day = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").split('-')

return datetime.date(year=int(year), month=int(month), day=int(day))

score["date"] = score.date.apply(parse_date)
```

I was getting the following error `ValueError: month must be in 1..12` which I believe is because the misrepresented dates have `mm` exceeding 12

How can I correct the misrepresented dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format` and `errors='coerce'` parameter, so if no match there is missing value and set new column by compare `Tuesday`s in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
score = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-06-04','2019-11-12','2021-03-09']})
    
d1 = pd.to_datetime(score.date, format="%Y-%m-%d", errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(score.date, format="%Y-%d-%m", errors='coerce')

#if both are Tuesdays is prioritize `d1`
score["date"] = np.where(d1.dt.weekday == 1, d1, d2)

print (score)
        date
0 2021-04-06
1 2019-11-12
2 2021-03-09
```

Also is possible compare `d2`:

```
#if both are Tuesdays is prioritize `d2`
score["date"] = np.where(d2.dt.weekday == 1, d2, d1)

print (score)
        date
0 2021-04-06
1 2019-11-12
2 2021-03-09
```

EDIT:

```
score = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-06-04','2019-12-11','2021-03-09']})
    
d1 = pd.to_datetime(score.date, format="%Y-%m-%d", errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(score.date, format="%Y-%d-%m", errors='coerce')

score["date"] = np.where(d2.dt.weekday == 1, d2, d1)

print (score)
        date
0 2021-04-06
1 2019-11-12
2 2021-03-09

score["date"] = np.where(d1.dt.weekday == 1, d1, d2)

print (score)
        date
0 2021-04-06
1 2019-11-12
2 2021-03-09
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for the `2019-12-11`. The data has `2019-12-11` but it should be `2019-11-12`

Comment: @WasswaSamuel - Do you think in `2019` or `2021` year?

Comment: Actually `2019-12-11` is a Wednesday and `2019-11-12` is a Tuesday

Comment: @WasswaSamuel - Default pandas datetiems are `YYYY-MM-DD` so `2019-11-12` is november

Comment: Change the value in the data frame to `2019-12-11`. Because the actual value in my data is `2019-12-11` and this should change to `2019-11-12`

Comment: @WasswaSamuel - added to answer, for me working well.

Comment: It should work but how would I apply this to a single column in the dataframe because my date column is a single column. I think columns are Pandas series.

Comment: `I apply this to a single column` - it is apply to column `date` in `d1 = pd.to_datetime(score.date, format="%Y-%m-%d", errors='coerce')` and in `d2 = pd.to_datetime(score.date, format="%Y-%d-%m", errors='coerce')`